# How do I move these buttons to the right?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm relatively new to HTML and CSS and I'm having trouble with moving the buttons pictured below, to the left of the toolbar, next to the tools like so:

[Moving the buttons left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot8u7.png)

I'm also wanting to have the buttons react in a similar way i.e the 'HiXXXX!' button size changes depending on how many characters are in the name in ZenDesk and the 'Hi!' button reacts by moving to accommodate the amount of characters, like so:

[Button changes size due to text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6wbf.png)

So if the buttons are moved to the left, it would be the 'Ask for a review' button (and another button that appears to the right when a certain event happens) that would react to the 'HiXXXX!' button changing it's size due to the amount of characters.

Here is the HTML/CSS (this is not mine, it was done by a work colleague who's long gone):

```
`GM_addStyle(`
    .trv_zd_editor_apps_button > button > span {
        line-height: 16p;`your text`

    }

`);

<div
                class="
          trv_zd_editor_apps_button
                    trv_zd_hi_button
                    trv_zd_hi_button_normal
                "
                data-trv-hi-button-name=""
            >
                <button
                    class="zendesk-editor--item"
                    type="button"
                >
                    <span>Hi!</span>
                </button>
            </div>


<div 
                class="
          trv_zd_editor_apps_button
                    trv_zd_hi_button
                    trv_zd_hi_button_with_name
                "
                data-trv-hi-button-name="${name}"
            >
                <button
                    class="zendesk-editor--item"
                    type="button"
                >
                    <span>Hi ${name}!</span>
                </button>
            </div>



            <div 
                class="
                    trv_zd_editor_apps_button
                    trv_zd_editor_apps_review_button
                "
            >
                <button
                    class="zendesk-editor--item"
                    type="button"
                >
                    <span>Ask for a review </span>
                </button>
            </div>


<div 
                class="
                    trv_zd_editor_apps_button
                    trv_zd_editor_apps_review_button_android
                "
            >
                <button
                    class="zendesk-editor--item"
                    type="button"
                >
                    <span>Ask for an Android review </span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

There is some Javascript involved for obvious reasons but I have not included it as I don't believe it's integral to what I am wanting to achieve here. I've also Googled this to death and can't seem to find a plausible answer. Here are my most recent attempts at making this happen:

````
GM_addStyle(`
    .trv_zd_editor_apps_button > button > span {
        line-height: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    }
`);

<div style="position:absolute;top:6px;right:630px;"
                class="
          trv_zd_editor_apps_button
                    trv_zd_hi_button
                    trv_zd_hi_button_normal
                "
                data-trv-hi-button-name=""
            >
                <button
                    class="zendesk-editor--item"
                    type="button"
                >
                    <span>Hi!</span>
                </button>
            </div>


<div style="position:absolute;top:6px;right:560px;"
                class="
          trv_zd_editor_apps_button
                    trv_zd_hi_button
                    trv_zd_hi_button_with_name
                "
                data-trv-hi-button-name="${name}"
            >
                <button
                    class="zendesk-editor--item"
                    type="button"
                >
                    <span>Hi ${name}!</span>
                </button>
            </div>



            <div style="position:absolute;top:6px;right:425px;"
                class="
                    trv_zd_editor_apps_button
                    trv_zd_editor_apps_review_button
                "
            >
                <button
                    class="zendesk-editor--item"
                    type="button"
                >
                    <span>Ask for a review </span>
                </button>
            </div>


<div style="position:absolute;top:6px;right:240px;"
                class="
                    trv_zd_editor_apps_button
                    trv_zd_editor_apps_review_button_android
                "
            >
                <button
                    class="zendesk-editor--item"
                    type="button"
                >
                    <span>Ask for an Android review </span>
                </button>
            </div>
```
`

As you can see, I get overlapping issues if there are more characters than usual:

[Ideal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax7mZ.png)
[Not ideal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efM2Y.png)
[Not ideal either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE9TL.png)

Any help would be hugely appreciated - thank you.





See above for my trial and errors.
````

Comment: Please can you provide a snippet code with preview. We can't help you without all the code html, css,...

Answer (score 0):

just warp all your buttons inside a div and give it a container class

```css
.container{
display:flex
flex-direction: row
float:left
}
```

and for dynamic sizing according to the amount of characters, give buttons width:fit-content